# will my "pages" table cause problem for my cakePHP set up

Tags: cakephp

I have table 'pages' in my database.

I have noticed that cakePHp has a app\views\pages folder

I dont want to use " table prefix " for my database table.

Will I have any issues in furture if I create my own pages model and controller files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though CakePHP makes intelligent guesses about which database table to use for a given model/controller, you can override it for a specific model if you need to so that it doesn't collide with your existing tables by using the `useTable` attribute: [docs here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/436/useTable)

Comment: Thanks, I'll go ahead with my database table as it is.

Answer (score 2):

In clean CakePHP project `app/views/pages` folder is empty and you can use it just like all other views. It is there so you could very easy start writing applications. Typically you would just add some actions to `PagesController` and views to `app/views/pages` but you can change that to act as a normal controller, so I don't think you should really worry about that.

Comment: thank you for the answers. I would require just the model and controller for table "pages" for my application.